# adding tapku calendar to ios app

Tags: ios, tapku

I'm building an IOS app which needs to use calendar. I'm confused what to use: iphone calendar `EventKit` or a calendar controller, what do you suggest?

I tried to use both but I could not because I'm very new in ios development, I use tapku calendar and I followed these steps but it dose not work... why?

Can anyone help me with [this](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary/wiki/Adding-Tapku-to-Your-Project-in-XCode-4) article? I followed the instructions as it is and it dose not work, I download the tapku and I ran the demo and also the demo dose not work, can you help me?

Comment: Sorry, but "it does not work" is meaningless. How isn't it working? Is it throwing any errors? If so, what are the errors.

Comment: mmmm i have several problems, ok lets say when i follow the instructions in the link
https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary/wiki/Adding-Tapku-to-Your-Project-in-XCode-4
i could not import tapku in my project.h

Comment: Do you see any red in 'Binary With Libraries group'.

Comment: do you mean the reference i added ?

Comment: @Tarek if you see in the link i attach in the previous comment i should have files under tapku library but i do not

Comment: if you knew what tapku means in french... :)

Comment: any one know how to import TapkuLibrary.xcodepro in my project in correct way ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add TapKu into your project

Go to File> Add New Files

Select both the .xcodeproj file and the bundle.

Now click on your main project settings. Go to Build Phases. Add dependency and TapKu framework as per the instructions on GitHub.

Now go to project Settings. Find header search paths option. Add in the location of your /src folder. I believe one reason why this shouldn't have worked for you is that somewhere in your location you might have a folder with a space in it's name. If so you need to put the directory in "".

Good Luck.